# What's the meaning of "in the spirit of"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The following is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2011/10/26/why_i_refuse_to_text_message/) article:

> In the spirit of full disclosure, the texter in question turned out to be my editor at Salon. (Hi, Sarah!) She has not texted me again.

What does *in the spirit of* in the passage mean? I have looked it up in the dictionaries, but couldn't find a definition for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In times past, the *rule of law* was **caveat emptor**, which is Latin for "let the buyer beware", placing the burden on the buyer to inspect goods before purchase, protecting those who would hide or falsify information about a product.

Relatively recently, this has changed to the need for [*full disclosure*](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/full+disclosure): the legal requirement to tell the "whole truth" about any matter which the other party should know in deciding to buy or contract.

There is the *letter of the law* and there is the *spirit of the law*. The *letter of the law* are the laws themselves; the *spirit of the law* is the principle behind the law (e.g. do not make false claims about your product).

There is no law that forces a writer to disclose every detail of how a particular situation came to be; there is likewise no *full disclosure* law governing something not bought (an article in an online magazine, for example.) So, writers will often cite *the spirit of full disclosure* to mean "full disclosure." It can be interpreted easily as

> - In all honesty...
> - Truth be told...

In this example, it is somewhat humorously used to disclose that the texter was someone she knew.

> In all honesty, the texter in question turned out to be my editor at Salon...

Answer (score 4):

It means in the thought or intention of.

> "In the thought or intention of" full disclosure, the texter in question turned out to be my editor at Salon. (Hi, Sarah!) She has not texted me again.

Edit: not quite sure why this has been down voted. Source: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=in+the+spirit+of+definition

Answer (score 3):

It means "in line with."

> **In line with** full disclosure, the texter in question turned out to be my editor at Salon.

We share the same idiom in France, "*dans l'esprit de*."

[In line with (=in the spirit of) full disclosure, I am posting this announcement so I can earn more points in my quest to win a copy.](http://rebeccaluellamiller.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/book-news-announcement/)